# How do I use active_model_serializers to include by default all attributes and filter them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and would like to find a way to include all model's attributes by default and then to use something like this

```
       exclude :date_created, :first_name
```

to specify the ones that I don't need.

Until now I didn't find a way to specify the exported attributes besides the one in the docs and that is done by enumerating all of the needed attributes:

```
       attributes :title, :body
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this on your model serializer (taking an example of User as the model):

```
class UserSerializer < ApplicationModelSerializer
   attributes(*User.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
end
```

More information about ActiveRecord attribute_names can be found here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attribute_names

Comment: Thank you. The final solution would be: `attributes(*(User.attribute_names - ["date_created", "first_name"] ).map(&:to_sym))`

Comment: I got an error for this, pls refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27701138/243797

Comment: unfortunately `attributes` does not accept an array as the input :(

Comment: @Tilo: That is why they us the asterisk (*) in front of the array. It will transform the Array into a parameter list.