# Undescriptive error when running spec, occurs dependent on seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have written a feature spec to test for correct multitenancy behaviour within my application. It signs in as two different users, creates a new `Presentation` by filling in a form and submitting it as each user, and confirms every time that only the tenant's own Presentations are visible to them.

This spec passes fine sometimes, and sometimes doesn't. What is really confusing is the error that occurs:

```
Failure/Error: click_button "Präsentation erstellen"
TypeError:
  can't cast ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess to
# ./app/controllers/presentations_controller.rb:21:in `create'
# ./spec/features/presentation_management_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and that is not a error at pasting, it literally says `can't cast ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess to` and just stops there. The referenced lines in context:

**./app/controllers/presentations_controller.rb**

```
18 def create
19  @presentation = Presentation.new(presentation_params)
20  
21  if @presentation.save
22    flash_for(@presentation, :create)
23    redirect_to @presentation
24  else
25    render :new
26  end
27 end
```

**./spec/features/presentation_management_spec.rb**

```
16 sign_in @user1
17
18 visit new_presentation_path
19 fill_in "Titel", with: title1
20 fill_in "Standard-Foliendauer", with: "60"
21
22 click_button "Präsentation erstellen"
23
24 page.should have_content "erfolgreich erstellt"
25 page.should have_content title1
```

and I don't see how that error makes any sense here, I'm just clicking a button that will create a new Presentation and save it. The saving itself throws the error. How? Why?

To make it worse, this **only occurs with some rspec seeds**. For instance, `48719` runs fine:

```
..........................................................................................

Finished in 48.17 seconds
90 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 48719
```

Which means that this error occurs only with some execution orders of the specs. But the error isn't descriptive at all, and I don't know what to do. I've tried resetting all databases, restarting my entire server, printing out the page where the button is pressed, commenting different lines out, and nothing would change, or even hint at what might be wrong.

Here's my Presentation model:

```
 class Presentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :properties, :bg_color, :bg_image

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :default_duration, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }

  def to_s
    title
  end

end
```

**EDIT**: I checked the test logs and found *this* in a failing case:

```
  SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "presentations" ("created_at", "default_duration", "properties", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2,
$3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 04 Feb 2014 20:56:26 UTC +00:00], ["default_duration", 60.0], ["properties", {"bg_
color"=>"#ffffff"}], ["title", "Example Presentation yo"], ["updated_at", Tue, 04 Feb 2014 20:56:26 UTC +00:00]]
TypeError: can't cast ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess to : INSERT INTO "presentations" ("created_at", "default_duration",
"properties", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
   (1.6ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms
```

and the only Hash here would be `{"bg_color"=>"#ffffff"}`, assigned to `properties`. The `properties` field is an `hstore` type. Maybe this is an issue with hstore, which might explain why the Rails error output was inable to put anything behind the `can't cast ... to`, because it's not a data type Rails truly natively understands?

**EDIT 2**:

I just now got the exact same error in development while trying to create a new `Presentation` on the rails console. My initial thought was that I had maybe left out the `hstore` schema in the `search_path`, but adding it did no good.

This confirms that it's not an issue of how the tests are written, but an actual coding problem. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: It is indeed a strange bug since it should normally manifest all the time and not randomly. I would do the following: firstly try to remove any parameters related to `properties` from your view so that you can see that it is this that causes the error. If it is that, then I would try to transform the request `params` object to a native `Hash` since they are `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` and that could be the problem.

Comment: The view is not what "causes" the problem. It's the controller, in `@presentation.save`, as can be read from the stacktrace.

Comment: I didn't mean that the exception happens at the view, but rather remove from the form view any parameters related to `properties` so that your controller won't see/process them.

Comment: Could you upload your gemfile? (Gist)

Comment: My Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/ch3stnut/b823200c71faaf469a09

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track that its related to saving the properties to your hstore data type as a prepared statement. Perhaps this answer will help you. :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074481/793330

Comment: I'm very sure it has something to do with hstore, but I'm not using prepared statements manually; and sadly the answer you have linked refers to a problem in Rails 3.2 where hstore wasn't natively supported. I'm using Rails 4.0.2 where it should be, and trying to add the code will tell me that `ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore` is an *uninitialized constant*.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

comment out the line below from spec_helper.rb if present.

```
config.order = "random"
```

And use [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to fix this issue,as this issues seems to be with data with which your test suite is running.

Comment: But wouldn't this remove the symptoms instead of fixing the issue? Maybe the error I'm getting here could happen in production too.

Comment: @yerforkferchips integrate database cleaner then to your test suite.

Comment: Again that's removing the symptoms, isn't it?

Comment: @yerforkferchips as we know `every test should run in isolation`, therefore, its good to have unique set of data for each test, hence there is no issue in adding database cleaner.

Comment: I just got this error while trying to create a record on the console, so it seems it's not just about the tests. Otherwise a nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in my Rails app. Finally I found that it was caused by the following code (using the [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) gem to serialize all attributes of User):

```
class UserSerializer < ApplicationModelSerializer
  attributes *User.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)
end
```

I changed the code to the following and then there were no errors:

```
class UserSerializer < ApplicationModelSerializer
  def attributes
    object.attributes
  end
end
```

I haven't found the real reason behind it yet. Hope it helps anyway.